# file_get_contents animated gif

Tags: php, file-get-contents, animated-gif

calling `file_get_contents` on the URL of an animated GIF (https://media.tenor.com/images/4f20af75f32887384aab7e49c37537ae/tenor.gif) and saving this content to a local file, will lose the animation.
[image: animation lost]

How can I keep the animation ?

thanks

Comment: Is it an option to use CURL instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321058/file-get-contents-returning-corrupted-image-from-url

Comment: Show your code saving image

Comment: Cannot reproduce, maybe post all of your code

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not alter the content. Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the use of the resize method of the Intervention/Image package, after the upload, which loses the animation.

I am now using imagick's convert command to resize the animated GIF, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
$imgData = file_get_contents('https://media.tenor.com/images/4f20af75f32887384aab7e49c37537ae/tenor.gif');
file_put_contents("saveto/file.giff", $imgData);
```

works for me with PHP 7.4.13. check write permissions

Comment: Indeed it works with file_put_contents. But I am using the Laravel framework and its Storage::put method, and in this case the animation is lost. With file_put_contents the file size is 216 ko, whereas with Storage::put the file size is 96 ko !

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220282/gif-lose-animation-on-upload 
 if my answer help you, please mark this question as resolved
@MaximeFreschard